# Spark - Error: Failed to load class - spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-submit

I create sbt project with Intellij and build Artifacts to jar file.
I put jar file to server and submit, but I got this error:

```
spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --class streaming_process spark-jar/spark-streaming.jar
```

> Error: Failed to load class streaming_process.
> 21/01/23 04:41:32 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
> 21/01/23 04:41:32 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-982e8fe3-9421-45bd-aced-e46c4d756054

My code

```
// Code Block 2 Starts Here
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("spark://master:7077")
      .appName("Stream Processing Application")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    // Code Block 2 Ends Here

    // Code Block 3 Starts Here
    // Stream meetup.com RSVP Message Data from Kafka
    val meetup_rsvp_df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers)
      .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .load()
```

You can see my project image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: Me too on WIndows 10. The same JAR, moved to MacOs, with a spark stand-alone installation, works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JVM can't find the jar which contains streaming_process class. Please use `--jars spark-jar/spark-streaming.jar` option.

Comment: I tried but got the same issue

`giangnt@node2:~/spark-jar$ spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --class streaming_process --jars spark-streaming.jar, spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.1.jar 
Error: Failed to load class streaming_process.
21/01/23 15:56:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/01/23 15:56:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-587836d9-1709-4c70-b549-34081d400f21
giangnt@node2:~/spark-jar$`

Comment: spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --class streaming_process --jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.1.jar spark-streaming.jar